# Why is CTAN china2e style package not in MacTex distribution?

Tags: mactex

I've just downloaded and installed MacTex in my mac, and opening the Tex Live Utility it seems that CTAN china2e style package is nowhere to be found.

Was it made obsolete by some other package?
I've searched and couldn't find out.

Answer (score 3):

See the license on http://ctan.org/pkg/china2e, the no sell license is not compatible with TeX Live.

Comment: *face-palm* noob question then :)
thanks